# Invalid column names for a Magento product import

Tags: magento, csv, import, e-commerce, export

I'm trying to upgrade from Magento Community to Magento Enterprise. I've got each installed seperately. I did a direct export of product from my Community installation and have attempted to directly import this to Enterprise.

Initially, the error I was received was

> 'csv' file extension is not supported

I did the following according to [a reply on a forum post](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/197451/P30/#t309123) from someone with a similar problem:

> Disable the Magento Compiler under System > Tools > Compilation

However, the next Validation Error I encountered was this:

> Column names: "_root_category", "_group_price_website", "_group_price_customer_group", "_group_price_price", "_media_attribute_id", "_media_image", "_media_lable", "_media_position", "_media_is_disabled" are invalid

I've done zero editing to the product CSV Magento provided me. I duplicated it, opened up the file and have found zero problems and zero duplicated columns.

I'm at a loss as to what to do next, any suggestions?

Sample CSV

Link: - [Google Docs Preview](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ag2Dx-KXLi9vdGVZSnpFdVNTRzJCbUFLQVBDNGxTb3c)

Link - [Google Drive Download](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Bw2Dx-KXLi9vMnJja3BlS0V2V00)

Answer (score -2):

Open in a text editor and save as UTF-8 encoding

Make sure you are using Import/Export > Import rather than the deprecated Dataflow method of import